# How to Delegate Control from a String to a series of functions in C

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

This is a performance critical part of my android application, and I am using the NDK (c) to process a large bitmap array.

```
int blender(const char* blendMode, int c1, int c2, int amount){

    int sob, sog, sor, soa, dsr, dsg, dsb, dsa = 0;

    dsr = Argb_GetRed(c1);
    dsg = Argb_GetGreen(c1);
    dsb = Argb_GetBlue(c1);
    dsa = Argb_GetAlpha(c1);

    sor = Argb_GetRed(c2);
    sog = Argb_GetGreen(c2);
    sob = Argb_GetBlue(c2);
    soa = Argb_GetAlpha(c2);


    int src_alpha, mix_alpha, dst_alpha;

    src_alpha = soa * ((255 * amount) / 100) >> 8;

    if (!strcmp(blendMode, "normal")) {
            PSD_BLEND_NORMAL(dsr, sor, mix_alpha);
            PSD_BLEND_NORMAL(dsg, sog, mix_alpha);
            PSD_BLEND_NORMAL(dsb, sob, mix_alpha);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(blendMode, "exclusion")) {

            mix_alpha = soa / 255;
            //.... it's not always just the 3 macros

            PSD_BLEND_EXCLUSION(dsr, sor, mix_alpha);
            PSD_BLEND_EXCLUSION(dsg, sog, mix_alpha);
            PSD_BLEND_EXCLUSION(dsb, sob, mix_alpha);
    }

    ~~~~~~~~~ X 20 or so blend modes ~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

Currently it's running this blender function on every pixel, and doing a switch (clearly inefficient)

also, it has to take the original command as a string (From json, and passed down through java)

I can think of a couple ways to make it more efficient, but they all involve writing 2 giant switch statements. I would prefer to use 1 switch statement, or lookup if possible

Thank you!

Comment: You could always instead of passing in a string, pass in a integer function code, that way you can do an acutal switch ( which will likely be compiled to something *very fast* )

Answer (score 1):

Pretty nasty problem but I got a "hackish" idea.

If the '*blendMode*' names are chosen nicely, you could compare only the *first two* (or *three*) letters of the strings. If there are multiple strings with same first letters, you could make a special case and compare first and third letter and so on.

This trick would make the code a lot faster than calling strcmp() all the time. Also inlining the compare function might help too.

Here is some code:

```
/* compares first two letters of the string */
inline int fast_cmp(const char *mode, const char *cmp) {
    return (mode[0] == cmp[0] && mode[1] == cmp[1]) ? 1 : 0;
}

if( fast_cmp(blendMode, "no") ); /* for "normal"    */
if( fast_cmp(blendMode, "ex") ); /* for "exclusion" */
```

In action: http://ideone.com/OiXS0

Ofcourse the comparisons could be written directly into if / else statements but it might get confusing. This can be fixed with small and nifty macro:

```
#define FAST_CMP(x, y) x[0] == y[0] && x[1] == y[1]
```

And here is the macro in action: http://ideone.com/NQFwW

This macro version is perhaps the fastest way to do the comparison.